# Spring Security OAuth2 and FormLogin in a one application

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

In my Spring Boot application I have RESTful API and MVC web dashboard for administration.

Is it possible to have both - Spring Security OAuth2 authentication/authorization(token based, stateless) for RESTful API and FormLogin(stateful) for Spring MVC web dashboard in a one application ?

How to properly configure it with Spring Boot ?

Comment: You can have multiple Spring Security configurations in the same app.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to configure your web security for form based login and Resource Server Security form REST Endpoints

Here is a working configuration that uses single sign on with an Authorization Server deployed separately.

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableWebSecurity
protected static class ResourceConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${sso.url}")
    private String ssoUrl;

    @Autowired
    private  RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    protected TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new RedisTokenStore(redisConnectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    protected ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);

        return defaultTokenServices;
    }


    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();
        authenticationManager.setTokenServices(tokenServices());
        return authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
        http.requestMatchers()
        .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/static/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/profile/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/services/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl(ssoUrl+"/logout")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll();
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(1)
protected static class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {



    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("resource-id");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(new OAuthRequestedMatcher())
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();

    }
}

private static class OAuthRequestedMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        boolean haveOauth2Token = (auth != null) && auth.startsWith("Bearer");
        boolean haveAccessToken = request.getParameter("access_token")!=null;
        return haveOauth2Token || haveAccessToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: you client app was done in thymeleaf? Just strange to have a logout url in Resource server

Comment: @rebert trudel , no, think it's not. Resource Server security configuration has only this 

`` 
@Override public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(new OAuthRequestedMatcher())
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();

    }
 ``

Comment: What are the maven dependencies that we need to add in the single pom.xml file? Also no issuer-uri is required to be defined right?