# SAML and Oauth2 in a single spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, authentication

In an attempt to develop a generic identity service for a project I am working on, I need to support Azure ADFS-based SAML security for UI pages and Oauth2 based security for my REST APIs in a single spring-boot application

I have a spring boot application attempting to provide SAML based protection for some of my UI resources and Oauth2 based protection for my REST APIs. The UI pages and the REST APIs are hosted in the same spring boot based application. I have a SecurityConfiguration class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and that contains my SAML configuration. I also have a ResourceServerConfig class that extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter where I have tried to configure the Oauth2 authentication for my REST APIs.

Here is what my code looks like

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

/////// Other methods //////
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class).addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

}
```

The ResourceServerConfig class looks something like the following

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends     ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
{
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .anonymous().and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
}
```

My problem is, with the above configuration in place, I can either get SAML protection on my UI pages OR Oauth2 protection on my APIs but not both. If I remove @EnableResourceServer from the ResourceServerConfig class and try to access one of my UI pages, I am reliably redirected to the microsoft Azure login page which redirects me back to my UI page after successful authentication. But with this, any attempt to access my apis (with valid bearer tokens) results in a redirection to the microsoft Azure login page. If I re-enable @EnableResourceServer my APIs get protected and behave as expected but SAML protection for all UI pages gets completely disabled with spring allowing unhindered access to all UI resources.

I can't figure out how to tell spring boot to use which authentication framework for the two kinds of URL patterns I have. Is such a thing even possible?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Regards,

Dipak Jha

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found an answer to my own question. [This reply here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51514005/10929421) provides a workable solution. A properly configured OAuthRequestedMatcher seems to do the trick. Please let me know if someone thinks this can be done in a better way.

Regards

Dipak Jha